# How to set a max amount of columns on row-cols-auto in bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="row row-cols-auto">
  <div id="vid_0"></div>
  <div id="vid_1"></div>
  <div id="vid_2"></div>
  <div id="vid_3"></div>
  <div id="vid_4"></div>
  <div id="vid_5"></div>
</div>
```

How do I make it so there is a maximum of 3 columns with auto columns?
Each div is a card with the class: `col`
I am using bootstrap

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have it both ways. You'd use `row-cols-3` instead of `row-cols-auto`.

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/#row-columns.